# Storing values from mongodb ​and validating

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

I always have been more interested in php and sql, but I decided to learn more about js. So, i created Quiz App. (reactjs, nodejs, and mongodb)
App works! Almost. There are some things I'm not happy with, and I don't know how to fix them.

api.js

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Quiz.aggregate([ { $sample: { size: 1 } } ])
        .then((data) => {
            console.log('Data: ', data);
            res.json(data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('erorr: ', error)
        })
});
```

App.js

```
  getQuestionAndAnswers = () => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/api')
      .then((response) => {
        const data = response.data;
        this.setState({posts: data});
        console.log('Data has been received');
      })
      .catch(() => {
        alert('Error retrieving data');
      })
  }


 displayQuiz = (posts) => {
    if (!posts.length) return null

    return posts.map((post, index) => (
      <div key={index}>
        <p>{post.question}</p>
        <button value={post.answer} onClick={(e) => this.checkAnswer(e, post)}><p>A. {post.answer}</p></button>
        <button value={post.answer2} onClick={(e) => this.checkAnswer(e, post)}><p>B. {post.answer2}</p></button>
      </div>
    ));
  };


 checkAnswer = (e,post) => {
    console.log(e.currentTarget.value);
    if(e.currentTarget.value === post.c_answer){
      console.log('correct');
    }else{
      console.log('incorrect');
    }
  };
```

As you can see, I store the data in button value, I don't think this is the best solution, because the answers stored there can be very big, but I have no idea how to do it better. So, I would have to change the answer checking, because at this point, I compare the correct answer with the clicked value, is there a better solution for that?

I would like to add a function thanks to which incorrect answers will change the color to red, and correct ones to green, I guess it is enough to add the css class after executing if(). It won't be difficult for me to do for the button I clicked, but what about the rest?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead passing event at `this.checkAnswer(e, post)` you can pass the answer to compare with `c_answer`. you could also create a separate component `Question`, where each `Question` component will have a state to check the answer status. you would use this status to define the class at `Question` component (it's better to control classes changes with props or state):

```
displayQuiz = (posts) => {
  if (!posts.length) return null

  return posts.map((post, index) => <Question post={post} key={index}>);
};
...

class Question extends React.Component {
  state = {
    answerStatus: 'pending'
  }

  checkAnswer = (answer, c_answer) => {
    const answerStatus = answer === c_answer ? 'right' : 'wrong';
    this.setState({ answerStatus });
  };

  getAnswerClass = () => {
    const { answerStatus } = this.state
    if ( answerStatus === 'pending') {
      return 'myPendingClass';
    }

    return answerStatus === 'right' ? 'myRightClass' : 'myWrongClass';
  }

  render() {
    const { answer, answer2, c_answer, question } = this.props.post;
    const answerClass = this.getAnswerClass();

    <div className={answerClass}>
      <p>{question}</p>
      <button onClick={(e) => this.checkAnswer(answer, c_answer)}><p>A. {answer}</p></button>
      <button onClick={(e) => this.checkAnswer(answer2, c_answer)}><p>B. {answer2}</p></button>
    </div>
  }
}
```

Comment: The getAnswerClass() function only returns myRightClass or myWrongClass, but we know that only one answer is correct and the rest are incorrect.
Is there any solution to return myRightClass to the correct answer, and myWrongClass to the wrong answer?
(In your code there is <div className = {answerClass}>, but I write this variable in <button className = {answerClass}>, because this variable will not be useful to me in <div>)